# C++ Linker Ignore Default Libs Error

Tags: c++, linker, c-preprocessor

Hello I'm trying to compile a simple test program to see how it works without linking any libraries.

Here is my code and my error:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define ENTRY_POINT main

INT ENTRY_POINT(void)
{
float a = 5.0f;
return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error  2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __fltused.

I have tried the following fix, but it doesn't work

```
extern "C"{
        int __fltused = NULL;
}
```

This gives me the multiple initialization error.
I have tried using

```
#undef __fltused
```

And then redefine it again but still getting the first error then.

Comment: Look here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/283246 and/or google "__fltused" and "_fltused".

Answer (score 0):

Any variables that start with a double underscore are reserved for the compiler implementation, so `__fltused` isn't something you can provide a work-around for.  If you want to test your code free of libraries, then don't include the header files that need them.

Comment: How can I fix my error then, I do not want to link default libs